# Run Java ScheduledExecutorService in the background

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice

I have jar file that runs a process every two minutes. It works perfectly but if someone closes the terminal the process is terminated. I am looking at a way of executing it as a background process. Here is my main:

```
public class SMSAlert {

    private static ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        Alert alert = new Alert();
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(alert, 0, 2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }

}
```

Comment: It sounds more like an OS issue than a programming issue. What OS are you using?

Comment: It does the same for both Linux mint and Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On linux, you can avoid the 'closing terminal kills process' problem by using the [screen](https://kb.iu.edu/d/acuy) command. This detaches the process from being affected by what happens to the terminal.

Another solution to your problem would be to run your application through [Cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). Once again, this makes its execution independent of any particular terminal session.